# Codeigniter update table when sorting with jquery sortable

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I just learn codeigniter, and I take an old project I did in php and convert it to CI. I used PDO before that and was easier for me to update things in the database. I have some problems now updating the list_order in my database.

This is my view

`echo "<li id=".$row->list_id." class='list_container'>" . $row->listTitle; ?> test </li>`

My js file which takes all the lists in the DOM and sends the value over to my controllers function

```
$(function() {
$('#sortable').sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    opacity: 0.7,
    handle: 'span',
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var list_sortable = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $.ajax({
            url: "lists/update_order",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {list_order:list_sortable},
           
 });
});
```

This is how my database is structured right now for the lists table

[image: screenshot]

How should I tell my controller to update the order the of the lists ?

Comment: Maybe you need to call $(this).sortable(...) only after the return ajax with success.

Comment: Codeigniter is PHP so not sure how that is impacting you in anyway.